# How to disable TAB completion for tags in Vim?

Tags: tags, vim, omnicomplete

I created tags file using ctags.

Now when I`m trying to use TAB for text completion from buffers I also see all tags in my popup.

How to prevent that and not show tags in completion popup?

I`m using SuperTab, without any options specified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this setting:

```
:set cpt-=t
```

---

The default value of `complete` option is `.,w,b,u,t,i`, which means to scan:

1. the current buffer
2. buffers in other windows
3. other loaded buffers
4. unloaded buffers
5. tags
6. included files